# SonarQube analysis via Maven fails with database access denied to MySQL

Tags: mysql, maven, teamcity, sonarqube

I have instances of MySQL, SonarQube, and TeamCity all running on the **same** Linux host.  All are very vanilla installations (out of the box / insecure / local / behind company firewall).

These are my Maven settings ... where `${fullyQualifiedDomainName}` is something like `build.company.com`

```
<profile>
  <id>env-dev</id>

  <properties>
    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
    <sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://${fullyQualifiedDomainName}:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8</sonar.jdbc.url>
    <sonar.jdbc.username>sonar</sonar.jdbc.username>
    <sonar.jdbc.password>sonar</sonar.jdbc.password>
    <sonar.host.url>http://${fullyQualifiedDomainName}:9000</sonar.host.url>
  </properties>

  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
</profile>
```

I run the command `mvn sonar:sonar` to perform and upload SonarQube analysis.

The Maven settings above work OK from my Windows PC.  However, if I run from the Linux server via TeamCity, I see this error: (giant Java stacktrace + ...):

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar (default-cli) on project IMQuant: 
Fail to connect to database:
Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory
(Access denied for user 'sonar'@'${fullyQualifiedDomainName}'
(using password: YES)) -> [Help 1]
```

If I switch to use `localhost` in the Maven settings it runs OK on the Linux server.  I am guessing this is one of the following issues:

1. MySQL config (I am a MySQL newbie)
2. Linux server config (network config / admin stuff beyond my control)
3. MySQL JDBC driver bug (`localhost` != fqdn from localhost)

For now I am using a second Maven profile in my settings for TeamCity / Linux with `localhost`.

Is there a solution for this issue?  Has anyone seen this issue?

## Update

Here are the commands to create my MySQL database for SonarQube.  As noted by @Mithfindel, it may be the root cause.

```
CREATE DATABASE sonar CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
CREATE USER 'sonar' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';
GRANT ALL ON sonar.* TO 'sonar'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';
GRANT ALL ON sonar.* TO 'sonar'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'sonar';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Ref: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/scripts/database/mysql/create_database.sql

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a MySQL configuration issue: for MySQL, a `GRANT` on localhost is different from a `GRANT` on localhost's FQDN. You might want to check which permissions are granted to users `'sonar'@'localhost'` and `'sonar'@'fqdn-of-localhost'` or `'sonar'@'%'`.